# Netty 3 HTTPS client hangs forever

Tags: https, netty

I have a Netty 3 client over HTTPS.

I can't puzzle out why it's not working and just hangs until timeout.
It works perfectly fine over HTTP (remove the SSL handler from the pipeline and change port from 443 to 80).

Here's a gist (in scala): https://gist.github.com/4396611

What am I doing wrong?

I've tested with Netty from 3.5.9 to 3.6.0.
My JDK is 1.6.0_37 on OS X.

Regards,

Stéphane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to issue the handshake once the channel is connected. The easiest way is to use setIssueHandshake on the SslHandler before add it to the pipeline.

http://static.netty.io/3.6/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/ssl/SslHandler.html#setIssueHandshake(boolean)

Comment: I added setIssueHandshake(true), but it still doesn't work. I updated the gist.

Comment: The second method from the javadoc (doing the handshake explicitly after connecting, and writing in a listener on the handshake future) actually work, thanks! I'll go this way but I'm still puzzled about why the first method didn't work.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue, but all the links here are dead. Are they available somewhere else?

Comment: Try this one : http://netty.io/3.6/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/ssl/SslHandler.html#setIssueHandshake(boolean